# Is there such thing as incremental build for OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, incremental-build, omake

Is there any tool that I can use to get the kind of incremental build like those from Eclipse/IntelliJ/Visual Studio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is called [OCaml Merlin](https://github.com/the-lambda-church/merlin). It supports incremental type-checking, IntelliSense-like completion, and code navigation. It works with Emacs, Vim out of the box, and third party extensions provide support for [Sublime](https://github.com/let-def/sublime-text-merlin) and [Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/hackwaly/vscode-ocaml).

Merlin can be easily installed via the OPAM package manager:

```
opam install merlin
```

Comment: not sure if this answers the question. ocaml usually builds to one executable file which means incremental compilation might be a little tricky

Comment: @rakim, I'm not sure how to address it :) I'm not even sure what Alexander means. OCaml compilation unit to a separate artifact, but honestly if it wasn't it won't impede separate compilation.